# Serilog - How to log messages in ascending order in text file?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

Currently, my Serilog implementation logs files in descending order - displays the oldest message at the top and the newest message at the bottom. I would like my implementation to log in ascending order - newest at the top and oldest at the bottom.

This is what I currently have in `Program.cs`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("[yyyy-MM-dd][HH.mm.ss tt]", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.File($"C:\\Logs\\{timestamp}-log.txt",
                outputTemplate: "Time:{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information
             )
            .CreateLogger();

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: as far as i know serilog does not support this. may be you can directly raise issue on [github](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) and serilog developers can tell if this is possible or not.

Comment: Writing to the start of a file means you need to copy all the stuff in the file to the end. And that needs to be done transactionally correct in the face of potentially multiple writers. That's simply not how Files can work in any reasonable way, so no real logging solutions do that. Logging servers on the other hand, typically let you see the most recent events first, but then they are indexing things

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1162

Answer (score 2):

This is not practical to implement given how files work on the bulk of current operating systems.

It would have the following downsides at least:

- extremely inefficient (all content after the new entry needs to be rewritten)
- where there aremultiple instances writing to the same file: results in much longer locking (Some file APIs let you concurrently
  append without losing data, whereas for prepending this would require
  a custom implementation)

Log aggregation servers typically present the data as you desire, and bring other advantages too.

[Canonical closed issue asking the same question](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/301).